# Problema com altura de divs que não acompanham o conteudo uma da outra

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou com um problema que creio eu ser fácil, mas não consigo entender como resolver.

Tenho uma estrutura do tipo:

```
 <div class="conteudo">
     <div class="esquerda">
     </div>
     <div class="direita">
     </div>
     <div class="clear">
     </div>
 </div>
```

Bom, o CSS é bem simples, a classe esquerda possui `float: left`, a direita possui `float: right`, e a clear o `clear:both;`

Até ai tudo bem, o problema é, o conteudo das divs, na verdade o da direita, é dinâmico, então o que acontece é que a div esquerda nao acompanha a altura da da direita, e o background que eu aplico fica só na altura ocupada pelo conteudo da div esquerda, deixando o layout totalmente errado.

Alguém saberia uma solução para isso? Parece-me que tem que se recorrer a js para isso?

Comment: Você pode utilizar flex box. Segue link com um ótimo tutorial http://tableless.com.br/flexbox-organizando-seu-layout/

Answer (score 6):

Uma solução seria utilizar o display **table** na div pai e display **table-cell** nos flhos, veja o css:

```
.conteudo {
    display:table;
    width:auto;  
}

.esquerda {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}

.direita {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    color:#fff;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Mas isso vai depender de como você quer o resultado final. Por exemplo, não podemos utilizar o ***float:right*** na div da direita.
Veja aqui o resultado: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2ZH2/

Caso não seja suficiente, procure no google sobre a técnica do **Faux-columns** ou **Equal Height Columns**.

Utilizando Jquery também é possível.
Aproveitando a solução do [@Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16210/6630) abaixo:

```
$(windows).load(function(){
    $('.esquerda').height($('.direita').height());
});
```

Utilizei o windows load porque assim garantimos que todos os elementos do DOM foram carregados, caso contrário a função "height" retornaria 0.

Comment: Muito obrigado Filipe, infelizmente estas duas técnicas não se aplicam tão facilmente ao layout, pois as duas colunas tem tamanhos variáveis, uma hora é uma, outra hora pode ser a outra. A Faux-columns falha rapidamente nisto, pois para ela funcionar precisamos de uma com tamanho mínimo o tempo todo. A display table até funcionou, mas quebrou um pouco o layout. Ele colocou um "padding-top" que não aparece no box model do chrome development tools na div da direita, =[, não encontro o CSS na lista que está pondo isto (e nem vou ver pois se tivesse estaria aparecendo no box model.)

Comment: padding-top onde? nas divs citadas acima?

Comment: Não diretamente filipe, tipo, a estrutura é semelhante, e o mesmo colocou esse padding na div direita. Eu tirei o float left e right das duas divs, e tentei tirando e deixando o clear (que nao faz diferença), mas ele sempre poe na div da direita.

Comment: Ele poe o padding de 12px que mandei na div da direita, mas na pratica ele exibe um padding top MUITO maior, sendo que no box model aparece apenas os 12px;

Comment: @user2752929 edita o scripr aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2ZH2/ no menu no topo tens o botão update. Após salvar, vai gerar um novo link, coloca aqui esse novo link para ver qual o problema.

Comment: @user2752929 O problema do padding parece não ser na resposta do Filipe, e sim algum elemento extra quebrando o layout. Provavelmente basta ajustar o "elemento culpado".

Comment: @user2752929 utilize jquery, editei o post com um exemplo no fim, ou então veja o post do Sergio, penso que tens tudo o que é necessário para resolver o problema.

Answer (score 4):

Na verdade não há necessidade de js.

Use estruturas de blocos e colunas para organizar.

```
.block{
height:auto;
float:left;
clear:both;
display:block;
}
.column {
height:auto;
float:left;
clear:none;
display:inline-block
}
```

Use estas classes para dar bloco e coluna para seus elementos e uma segunda classe para dar a largura e altura se for este o caso.
Com esse tipo de estrutura em blocos e tendo um container para as colunas, o seu bloco que segura as colunas irá assumir a altura da maior coluna garantindo o alinhamento.

Prefira dar alinhamento a esquerda para evitar fazer fix para o IE

Answer (score 2):

Eu acredito que a solução aqui passa por `display: table` / `table-row` / `table-cell` como o [@Filipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16175/129) referiu.

Porém, para completar as respostas e porque o jQuery está nas tags, aqui fica uma sugestão com jQuery. Neste código que você apresenta existe só uma div `.esquerda` e uma div `.direita`. Se forem mais, o meu código tem de ser adaptado para algo como [**isto (link)**](http://jsfiddle.net/zYx87/1/). Mas como está na pergunta basta assim:

http://jsfiddle.net/zYx87/

```
$('.esquerda').height($('.direita').height());
```

---

Se o seu conteúdo for adicionado dinamicamente, a única opção que me ocorre com Javascript/jQuery é ter um `setInterval` que procura mudanças de tamanho na div `.direita` e faz a div `.esquerda` ficar do mesmo tamanho. Em termos de performance não é o mais indicado, mas funciona.

http://jsfiddle.net/zYx87/2/

```
var $direita = $('.direita');
var alturaInicial = 0;
$direita.on('resize change', function () {
    $('.esquerda').height($(this).height());
});

setInterval(function () {
    var novaAltura = $direita.height();
    if (alturaInicial != novaAltura) $direita.resize();
    alturaInicial = novaAltura;
}, 100);
```

Comment: Ele pode utilizar o $(windows).load() e após isso verificar qual div é maior, esquerda ou direita e aplicar a solução que você escreveu acima sem utilizar o setInterval. Caso o conteúdo seja adicionado via ajax, poderá inserir o código acima no "done", sem a necessidade do setInterval.

Comment: @Filipe concordo. Respondi assim por falta de informação na pergunta...

Answer (score 2):

Uma sugestão com flex seria usar assim:

```css
.pai {
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.pai > .coluna-1, .pai > .coluna-2 {
    width: 50%;
}

.pai > .coluna-1 {
     background: #f00;
}

.pai > .coluna-2 {
     background: #fc0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
     <div class="coluna-1">foo bar</div>
     <div class="coluna-2">
     foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br>
     </div>
</div>
```

É necessário o elemento pai, as propriedades são para navegadores mais antigos, como Androids antigos e IE10/IE11:

```
display: -ms-flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
```

Pode colocar quantas colunas quiser, basta ajustar o `width` em porcentagem se baseando na quantidade de colunas.

Claro que isto para navegadores que suportem *flex*, então depende do seu projeto, pode conferir no `caniuse` os navegadores que fazem uso do suporte básico do flex:

- https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox