# Deixar lado esquerdo e direito com height 100% independente do tamanho do conteudo

Tags: css, html5, front-end, flexbox

```css
.box {
   display: flex;
   height: 200px;
   max-height: 50%;
   margin: 10%;
   background-color: aqua;
   overflow: scroll;
}

.item {
   width: 50%;   
}

.esquerda {
   background-color: brown;
}

.direita {
   background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item">
     <div class="esquerda">
           esquerda
     </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
        <div class="direita">
           direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>
           direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>

        </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Vc vai usar cores para saber se uma div é da mesma altura da outra? Vc poderia usar uma cor na div direita e uma cor no box todo, dando a impressão que as duas divs são da mesma altura.

Comment: Esse é um exemplo basic que fiz pra vcs entenderem o problema. O modal original não daria pra fazer isso.  Ele tem outra cor de fundo, margem, etc...

Comment: Uma sugestão com flex: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/325574/3635 (já que você adicionou a tag)

Comment: Sim, o flex por padrão deixa todo mundo com o mesmo tamanho. Só que meu problema acontece quando tenho scroll nessa div pai.

Comment: Usando JavaScript vc consegue: `document.querySelector(".esquerda").style.height = document.querySelector(".direita").offsetHeight+"px";`, mas já tem uma versão em jQuery [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16175/8063)

Comment: Eu gostaria de resolver o problema no proprio css, mas como uma alteranativa caso eu não consiga, vou usar essa solução mesmo. Deu certinho, obrigada :D

Comment: @LaianeHermes basta criar um elemento "avô" e colocar o overflow nele, e no elemento pai colocar o display:flex, exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/325653/3635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como respondi em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/325574/3635

Mas para resolver o problema do overflow bastaria criar um elemento "avô", assim:

```css
.avo {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 400px; /*altura fixa*/
}

.pai {
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.pai > .coluna-1, .pai > .coluna-2 {
    width: 50%;
}

.pai > .coluna-1 {
     background: #f00;
}

.pai > .coluna-2 {
     background: #fc0;
}
```

```html
<div class="avo">
    <div class="pai">
        <div class="coluna-1">
           foo bar
        </div>
        <div class="coluna-2">
           foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br>
           foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br>
           foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br>
           foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br>
           foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br>
           foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br> foo baz<br>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

É necessário o elemento pai, as propriedades são para navegadores mais antigos, como Androids antigos e IE10/IE11:

```
display: -ms-flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
```

Pode colocar quantas colunas quiser, basta ajustar o `width` em porcentagem se baseando na quantidade de colunas.

Claro que isto para navegadores que suportem *flex*, então depende do seu projeto, pode conferir no `caniuse` os navegadores que fazem uso do suporte básico do flex:

- https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Parece que o container flex misturado com scroll é que está dando problemas. Veja esta minha solução, com o HTML um pouco modificado tanto nos itens, que agora juntam item e esquerda/direita no mesmo div, quanto na criação de um div mais externo para o scroll.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.esquerda {
  background-color: brown;
}

.direita {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.outerbox {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerbox">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="item esquerda">
      esquerda
    </div>

    <div class="item direita">
      direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br> direita
      <br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>direita<br>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```